# numbered_pagination for news – how to get it working

Tags: pagination, typo3

Tried to get the numbered_pagination extension to work inside news.

– Just installing the numbered_pagination extension doesn't bring any difference.
– The template Partials/Pagination.html is the same as the new news-9 Partials/Pagination.html

But how to tell news to use the other classes from the numbered_pagination extension.

Manaual only covers how to integrate it in a new extension.

Any body any idea?
Looking for something that shows how many pages are available and then a navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The manual of EXT:numbered_pagination describes:

> Copy the pagination partial EXT:numbered_pagination/Resources/Private/Partials/Pagination.html to your extension

So, in your case of using the extension with EXT:news, you have to copy the partial to a `partialRootPaths` entry you have configured for news - that's it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The Pagination.html of news 9.x in the Partials area is the same as the Pagination.html that comes with EXT:numbered_pagination and the output is the same with a active EXT:numbered_pagination or with a disabled extension.

So my asumption is that somewhere inside news one must tell news to use the classes of the extenision numbered_pagination and not the classes of TYPO3 simplePagination.

E.g. I don't get any "…" in my output as described in the manual.

Comment: Hm... sorry, guessing is not always the best base for answers :-/
So, let's look into the code: the `list`-action must handle the pagination - and is doing so: https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/main/Classes/Controller/NewsController.php#L238 The numbered_pagination is used if the condition `$paginationClass === NumberedPagination::class && $maximumNumberOfLinks && class_exists(NumberedPagination::class)` matches. If EXT:numbered_pagniation is installed and the static template of EXT:news is included (setup.typoscript#L151), all three conditions should be true.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In my case (only 5 resulting pages) with or without the numbered-extension is the output just the same. Checked again the two templates Pagintaion.html that comes with news 9 and the one that comes with numbered_pagination. The difference is an "addQueryString:1" in the uri viewhelper of the news template, that is missing in the template of the numbered_pagination template. So Georg Ringer made it for news very simple, just install the numbered_pagination extension and go? And differences will only show with bigger paginated page numbers?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `NumberedPagination::class` for **EXT:news**, you have to set this class name in TypoScript setup like this:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.list.paginate.class = GeorgRinger\NumberedPagination\NumberedPagination
```

It is done like this because Georg wants to make it so you can also use your own class for pagination.